# How to search in the multiple tables data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, search

I'm new to Laravel, how get the multiples tables data for filter search purpose? I already view the data like id, topic name, standard name subject name but I searching topic it show topic name only but I need whatever I search its show the full data.

This is my tables name and what I need columns (three tables are different)

```
1. Topics -> id, topic_name
2. Standards -> standard_name
3. subject -> subject_name
```

This is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\TopicRequest;
use App\Topic;
use App\Standard;
use App\Subject;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TopicController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     **/
     public function index()
     {
          $topics = Topic::leftJoin('standards','topics.standard_id', '=', 'standards.id')->
                   leftJoin('subjects','topics.subject_id', '=', 'subjects.id')
         ->select('topics.*' ,'standards.standard_name','subjects.subject_name')
         ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
         ->paginate(10);
         return view('topic.index', compact('topics'));
     }
    public function create()
    {
        $standards = Standard::select('id','standard_name')->paginate(10);
        $subjects = Subject::select('id','subject_name')->paginate(10);
        return view('topic.create', compact('standards','subjects'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'    =>  'required',
            'standard_id' => 'required',
            'subject_id' => 'required',
        ]);
        $topic = new Topic([
            'topic_name'    =>  $request->get('name'),
            'standard_id'    =>  $request->get('standard_id'),
            'subject_id'    =>  $request->get('subject_id'),
        ]);
        $topic->save();
        return redirect()->route('topic.index')->with('success', 'Data Added');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $topic = Topic::find($id);
        $standards = Standard::select('id','standard_name')->paginate(10);
        $subjects = Subject::select('id','subject_name')->paginate(10);
        return view('topic.edit', compact('topic', 'id','standards','subjects'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $topic = Topic::find($id);
        $topic->topic_name = $request->get('name');
        $topic->standard_id = $request->get('standard_id');
        $topic->subject_id = $request->get('subject_id');
        $topic->save();
        return redirect()->route('topic.index')->with('success', 'Data Updated');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $topic = Topic::find($id);
        $topic->delete();
        return redirect()->route('topic.index')->with('success', 'Data Deleted');
    }
     public function search()
    {

        $search = Input::get('search');
        $topics = Topic::where( 'id', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' )->orwhere( 'topic_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' )->paginate(10);
        return view('topic.index',compact('topics'));


    }
}
```

Comment: What is your search keyword name?

Comment: Topic name is Grammer

Comment: Means where you want searching

Comment: if you are getting value from request what is variable name

Comment: It will be good if you discuss here

Answer (score 0):

If the search in the tables will be independent of each other; you must list the results separately by performing a separate search on each table.

If the tables to be searched depend on the search results in other tables, you cannot do this with eloquent orm. You must type raw sql.

If this is going to be a common procedure, I suggest you search for elastic search.